# Can we deduce whether $f \in \mathcal{L}^2$ given these conditions on $f$?

Tags: continuity, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, fourier-series

> If we assume that $f$ is a real-valued and continously differentiable. Let's also assume that $f(x) = f(x+2\pi) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can we then deduce something about the following statements:
>
> 1. $f \in \mathcal{L^2}(-\pi, \pi)$
> 2. $f' \in \mathcal{L^2}(-\pi, \pi)$
> 3. $\langle f , f' \rangle$

---

**My attempt:**

If $f$ is continously differentiable, then both $f$ and $f'$ are continous on the reals. If $f$ is continous on a bounded interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, then it attains a maximum $M_f$ and likewise $M_{f'}$ for $f'$.

From the definition of $\mathcal{L^2}(-\pi, \pi)$, we can bound both $f$ and $f'$ such that:

$$\int_{-pi}^\pi |f|^2 \leq 2 M_f^2 \pi $$

and correspondingly with $f'$. So both of them must be in $\mathcal{L^2}(-\pi, \pi)$.

For the last statement, we use the definition:

$\langle f , f' \rangle := \int_{-\pi}^\pi f f' dx$

Since $f'$ and $f$ are continous, $f'f$ is also continous on $[-\pi, \pi]$, which means that we can deduce that this integral is finite.

Is this a correct way of thinking about these problems? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, correct. You could as well deduce 3 from 1 and 2.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your comment. I just came to realization that it was included that the function is periodic in the problem. It seems like I'm missing something, since I didn't use that fact anywhere.

Comment: You don't need it since your integrals are only over a period.

Comment: You can say something more about the integral in 3 if you use the periodicity. Hint: integration by parts.

Comment: What do you mean in (3)? It isn't a statement as written...

Comment: @MPW Sorry, I understand my formulation caused some confusion for (3). I really meant: what can you deduce about $\langle f, f' \rangle$ for the given conditions.

Comment: @MaoWao I'll test that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor: you have to pick $M_f$ as maximum of $|f|$.

As to (3): we have $(f^2)' = 2ff'$, so
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi ff' \ dx = \frac12( f(\pi)^2 - f(-\pi)^2) = 0
$$
because of periodicity.